# Right function for a metric that grows steadily

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a counter `cart_transactions_messages_processed_total`. Trying to set an alert, if the counter increases continually during/for an hour.

From the documentation, I learnt that, if the counter value drops the counter resets altogether, if so, how to take this into consideration while creating a rule ?

Will this be a right approach - `increase(cart_transactions_messages_processed_total[1h])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`increase(cart_transactions_messages_processed_total[1h])` returns increase of your counter over an hour.

Based on your question, I assume you want to fire alert, if counter was increased every minute of some hour. If this is correct, you'll need something like this:

```yaml
  - alert: ConstantIncrease
    expr: increase(cart_transactions_messages_processed_total[1m]) > 0
    for: 1h
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: Counter is constantly increasing
```

Here, expression `increase(cart_transactions_messages_processed_total[1m]) > 0` executed every `evaluation_interval`, and if it returns result for one hour, alert will be fired.

Comment: Thanks @markalex. I assume it accounts for the reset of counter, am I right ?

Comment: @ChelMS, yes, `increase` accounts for counter resets.

Answer (score 0):

**No** This is not Right Approach

The "increase" function calculates the difference btw first & last value within the specified time range,which would not capture the steady increase over time.

Instead, you should use the "rate" function

**rate(cart_transactions_messages_processed_total[1h])**

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong here. What you stated is applicable for delta().
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta
The "Increase" function calculates how much the counter is increasing in the time range.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. How rate over one hour supposed to be used in alert for described conditions?